# xsl 1.0 xml table to html table, replace empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML table that looks like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<table frame="all" colsep="1" rowsep="1">
  <tgroup>
    <colspec colname="col0" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col2" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col3" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col4" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col5" colwidth="1316"/>
    <colspec colname="col6" colwidth="1316"/>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <p/>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

And I want it to convert this to a HTML table, I've made an XSL transformation but it doesn't copy the empty paragraphs.
I want to check the inside of every entry and if there empty of have an empty <p> I want to replace it to '<p>&nbsp;</p>' and if it has a textnode I want to surround this with a <p> also.

This is the current XSL of the entry:

```
<!-- language: lang-xsl -->

<xsl:template match="entry">
  <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="*" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::text()[not(text()='')]" >
          <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::text()[text()='']" >
          <p>&amp;nbsp;</p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="text()=''" >
          <p>&amp;nbsp;</p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="p[not(node())]" >
          <p>&amp;nbsp;</p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSL 1.0 and it doesn't give the result I expect.
Basically I get a load of empty <td></td> tags.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the rest of the XSL, but this part might help in getting the solution:

```
  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:if test="not(text())"><p>&amp;nbsp;</p></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="text()">
      <p><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></p>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your solution almost worked.
I Added this and made the entry apply templates:

  `<xsl:template match="entry/p | td/p">
    <xsl:if test="not(text())">
      <p>&amp;nbsp;</p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="text()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
          <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
          </p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <p>&amp;nbsp;</p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>`
It now adds a <p> element inside of the td but no &nbsp;
Anyway it works! thanks

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer You should test your solution with `<p><i>italic</i></p>` and `<p>Some <b>bold</b> text</p>`.

Comment: @ThomasW. And so should you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: it was not mentioned that there can be arbitrary HTML inside `<p>`.

Comment: True, but the opposite was not mentioned either. I have nothing against assumptions, but they need to be stated.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your *other* templates would be helpful. Without it, we can't tell what this part does:

```
<p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</p>
```

Assuming it works as expected, try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="p/node()">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>   
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or perhaps (not depending on further templates):

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="p/node()">
                <xsl:copy-of select="p/node()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>   
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```